# Error --> Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles

Tags: matlab, class, runtime-error

I have the following two matrices:

**fuzzySet**

```
255  7  7
255  7  7
255  7  7
```

**membershipMatrix**

```
2.881749158360024e-04   0.999999819474077   0.904200609951489
0.0336048930092375      0.517034652401936   0.847219463816453
2.881749158360024e-04   0.999999819474077   0.904200609951489
```

When I tried running this code portion:

```
tolerance = 0.01; 
core = double(fuzzySet.*(abs(membershipMatrix-1) <= tolerance)) + membershipMatrix.*(membershipMatrix.*(abs(membershipMatrix-1) > tolerance););
```

I got the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> times
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.

Error in ==> fs at 36
core = fuzzySet.*(abs(membershipMatrix-1) <= tolerance) +
membershipMatrix.*(membershipMatrix > tolerance);
```

How can I work around this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

put the double just around fuzzySet?

```
double(fuzzySet).*(abs(membershipMatrix-1) <= tolerance)
```