# Hard Thresholding with Matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have an error that

```
Error using  .* 
Integers can only be combined with integers of the same class, or scalar doubles.

Error in wthresh (line 27)
    y   = x.*(abs(x)>t);
```

Comment: I don't have wthresh(), but I expect you need to convert I to double, it will have come in as uint8. Do `I = double(I)`.

Comment: When I use double, original image is so changing and going too white.

Comment: Yeah, if you want to display it, `image()` expects it to be scaled in 0-1 if it's double, vs 0-255 if it's uint8. Given your threshold, what you're probably after, actually, is I = double(I)/255, which rescales it to 0-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error message is pretty clear. You are multiplying `x` which might be a uint8 and `(abs(x)>t)` which is a logical. You need same types when multiplying integers or convert to a double. Look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15591263/error-integers-can-only-be-combined-with-integers-of-the-same-class-or-scal) too. Change your code to the following:

```
I = im2double(imread('cameraman.tif')); %Converting pixel values from [0,255] to [0,1]
thr = 0.4;
hard= wthresh(I,'h',thr);
imshow(hard,[]);
```

Or

```
I = double(imread('cameraman.tif')); % Just change the data-type but keep values 
                                     % in the range [0,255].
thr = round(0.4*255); %Instead of converting pixel values, change the threshold.
hard= wthresh(I,'h',thr);
```